# Permission problem with bitmap.Save()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, permissions

I have this simple code:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = bitmapSourceToBitmap(source);
try
            {
                bm.Save(@"C:\Seva\testeImagem.jpg");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

This throws: Generic Error GDI+.
Anyway, I seached and people say that the problem is with permissions. How can I give permissions to it?  Thanks

Comment: Can you post the exact exception?

Answer (score 1):

First find out under what credentials the code is running.

Then check (and, when needed, fix) the security/NTFS settings of the Seva folder.

Especially when this code is running from within a website or service the account will not have permissions to write to the folder.

Comment: I'm using WPF, this is not web. But some days ago I could save some things in that folder

Comment: Check the permissions, I can't do that for you. What worked days ago might not work today when things have changed.

Answer (score 0):

instead of saving to C:\Seva\testeImagem.jpg why not try saving to

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), 
             "testeImagem.jpg");
```

You must ensure that the Seva folder exists under C:\ and ensure that the current user has permissions to write to\create this folder.  Also, its considered bad practice to write to folders that the user doesn't own.  If the user is Running As A Normal User (not an admin) failure to do so results in permission exceptions.

Comment: I guess I found another problem in my code. This still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you test if the folder exists?

```
void BitmapCopy(System.Drawing.Bitmap source, string filename) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) && (source != null)) {
    string dirName = @"C:\Seva";
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirName)) {
      dirName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    }
    string bmpFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirName, filename);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = bitmapSourceToBitmap(source);
    try {
      bm.Save(bmpFile);
    } catch (ArgumentNullException ex) {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    } catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException ex) {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

  }
}
```